# Creating a repository using sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create a library in sharepoint in such a way that once a file is created in a folder it should create a folder structure as specified by us.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the help of an event handler. Write an event receiver for the document library. Add your code logic in the itemadded event which gets fired when an item is created in your document library. Put logic in your event receiver that it should create a folder structure as defined by you in your code. Now deploy the code(wsp) in your SharePoint farm and it should work as expected.
Follow this link to get help about how to create an event receiver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx